# Remove seenote reference from verbose-inote style

Tags: biblatex, formatting

In a book project, I want to remove the "See note ..." field from citations in footnotes when referring to an already cited work. My citation style `verbose-inote` quotes these cases as: Author. (Short)Title, see. n. XX. I want to get rid of the "See n. XX". See MWE.

How can I do that? I've tried, without success:
`\renewbibmacro*{cite:seenote}{}`
as suggested for the `biblatex-dw` style. But this macro is not defined in `verbose-inote`.

Just switching to another style is not an option because it is very close to my needs, I already had to make hefty customizations to `verbose-inote` and the book is pretty close to being ready to print.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{AB,
         author    = {Author Beta},
         title     = {Title},
         shortjournal = {ABC},
         journal ={AllButCrash},
         pages = {1-23},
         year={2009}}
@ARTICLE{AB2,
         author    = {Author Beta},
         title     = {Title2},
         shortjournal = {No ABC},
         journal ={Not AllButCrash},
         pages = {1-42},
         year={2019}}
@ARTICLE{CD,
         author    = {Changed Director},
         title     = {Title},
         journal ={Boring Texts},
         pages = {23-42},
         year={2019}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-inote,sorting=nyt,bibencoding=utf8,citereset=chapter,citepages=separate,refsection=none,autocite=footnote,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,eprint=false,date=short]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
A reference here.\footcite{AB,AB2} See also.\footcite{CD} However, second quote should be shortened but without "`See note"'.\footcite{AB} Equally.\footcites{AB2}[and][]{CD}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "see note" bit is coded directly into the `footcite:note` bibmacro ([`verbose-inote.cbx`, ll. 165-183](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/verbose-inote.cbx#L165-L183)), to remove it we simply remove the last bit of the macro.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=verbose-inote,
  sorting=nyt,
  refsection=none,
  citereset=chapter,
  autocite=footnote,
  isbn=false, doi=false, url=false, eprint=false,
  date=short,
  citepages=separate,]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
A reference here.\footcite{sigfridsson,worman}
See also.\footcite{nussbaum}
However, second quote should be shortened but without "`See note"'.\footcite{sigfridsson}
Equally.\footcites{worman}[and][]{nussbaum}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde.//Worman; and Nussbaum.]

Note that I find using `sorting=nyt,` with `style=verbose-inote,` questionable, since the work is primarily cited with author and title, so that it would be more natural to sort by name-title-year (the default `sorting=nty,`).

Comment: Happy new year to you and your family too....

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thank you very much! All the best to you and your loved ones for the new year as well.

Comment: @moewe I know it's frowned upon, but since you helped so much, and now even between Xmas and New Year: thank you and a happy New Year from me, too! Your suggestion worked, of course.

Comment: @shevek Thank you. Happy new year! (I personally don't mind the odd thank you comment: They can be very nice gestures.)